# how to use json object in html ActionLlink helper method with query string?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, html

I am using below anchor tag,in using json object.How to write it using html helper method.

```
success: function (data) {
    var str = "";
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        str += "<a href=/Home/GetArtistRelatedData?str=" + data[i].ArtistName + " target='_blank' style='color:gold;'>" + data[i].ArtistName + "</a><br/>";
    }
    $("#mm").append(str);
}
```

Comment: You cant - razor code is parsed on the server before its sent to the view and your javascript variables do not even exist at that point